# Replacing quotes with single quotes between two strings in php using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for a preg_replace that can replace " with ' when between font-family: and ;

I'm having an issue with my some dynamic html I'm using which requires me to replace the quotes with single quotes in my style attribute. Font and Font-family attributes can sometimes have quotes when they have spaces in the names but that is causing issues rendering the html. I haven't fully got a handle on how to use preg_replace so I'm hoping somebody can lend me a hand.

This is an example of the string: `<span style="font-weight:bold;font-family:"franklin gothic medium",arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:29px"="">Made in the USA!</span>`

From how I though preg_replace worked I tried the following but it didn't work: `preg_replace("/font\-family\:[\"]+?\;/", "'", $string);`

Comment: Are you sure you cannot change the `"` to `'` at the source of this problem? That would make live a lot easier. In general it is not advisable to try and modify HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Unfortunately the HTML is generated outside of my control. I'm just importing the html and redisplaying and saving the html to my database.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Do they know they are generating invalid HTML? Why use such a buggy source of HTML?

Comment: The issue is likely other places in the source as well. The issue you've described in question could be solved with `preg_replace('/font-family:\K"([^"]+?)"/', "'$1'", $string);`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I thought the same thing. If the style is added after the fact through jQuery it does actually render properly. It just doesn't render properly if done right through HTML.

Comment: @user3783243 Unfortunately this is the real source generated. I know if I add the same style though jQuery it does actually render. It just doesn't work if it's hardcoded HTML. I will try looking into preg_replace_callback

Comment: So it's not the HTML in your question you get from the "outside", it's only the style string? And then you put that string into the HTML yourself?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The html is what I get from the outside. I take that html and render it into an iFrame and I also send an email with the html preview inserted.

Comment: I don't know how much your HTML is varying, but if it varies a lot it will be very difficult to do what you want. We haven't even talked about the weird `=""` that's also present in the HTML. Since you're unwilling to give any real details about how you got this corrupted HTML, I think it is best to close this question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware This is practically an in house marketing system. This HTML can come from many sources. So what I'm doing is allowing people to create draft emails in GMail, which I then take and recreate to and send it out. So this particular email I'm using was a previous HTML E-blast we had sent out using Constant Contact.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. The question is getting less clear to me. If the issue is with users generating invalid templates why not tell the user they generated invalid content and to correct i?

Comment: @user3783243 It does seem like an issue out of my control. However, your answer did answer what my original question was with the example I gave, so I would like to select it if you repost it.